# Create Unique ID from 0 to Upward Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where data is being added to the last empty row and inserting the new row between the rows which has already data.

I want to create a Unique Numeric number that will be 0 to upward in sequence. Like we use `=IF(B3<>"",B2+1,"")`.

But when new row is added the formula is missed I want to Add unique number for each row.

Because when you insert the row all values are bonded but when you type anything in newly added row in Col B all the number goes disturb. It should work like timestamp once a number is allotted to specific row data it should not change even new row is inserted within data.

For example If script has assigned number 1 to 7 and new row inserted then it should assign new row a number 8 even new row is inserted with data in col B

Your help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sample sheet with similar data to your actual sheet for replication? Or will you be willing to share at a least a screenshot of your desired goal (specially how it will look like when you said `create a Unique Numeric number that will be 0 to upward in sequence`? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: About sharing spreadsheets, do note that [it exposes your email address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). So, use a dummy Google account if you consider your email address to be private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ALTERNATIVE SUGGESTION

If I have understood your goal correctly, you may try this custom script below that you can [copy and paste as a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#google_sheets) to your Spreadsheet file:

### *UPDATED* Script

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getRange("B2:B").getValues().filter(String); //Add the range where data you want to have IDs, on my end, it's B2 and below (B2:B)
  var ids = [];
  var lastRow;

 for(row=0; row<=data.length-1; row++){
   ids.push([row]);
 }

 lastRow = ids.length + 1;
 ss.getRange("A2:A"+lastRow).setValues(ids);

}
```

### SAMPLE DEMONSTRATION

> The custom function will add IDs starting on the cell `A2` and below once you run it for the first time from the Apps Script editor:

[image]

> When new added data on cell `B10` has been entered:

[image]

Comment: Thanks i was exactly looking for this solution but was unable to elaborate. There is one problem it should not use any formula in sheet. Because when you insert the row all values are bonded but when you type anything in newly added row in Col B all the number goes disturb. Ti should work like `timestamp` once a number is allotted to specific row data it should not change even new row is inserted with data. @Irvin Jay G. For example If script has assigned number 1 to 7 and new row inserted then it should assign new row a number 8 even wherever the row is inserted with data in col B

Comment: Wouldn't then a unique id from your yagi link be more appropriate? Why do you need serialization from 0,1,2..?

Comment: I see, please update your post just to make sure it reflects your actual goal. I have updated my answer, which uses an `onEdit` trigger, so it auto adds new row number every time you enter a new data on column `B` using your keyboard.

Comment: I have updated the post, I just added the link to show script or formula should work like this but it has to increment the number.

Comment: I have been facing an problem whenever i reference the two different sheets in the script where the ranges are different it gives me an error `The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 65 but the range has 62.` but when i use the same range it works fine. @Irvin Jay G.

Answer (score 0):

In the top row,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"ID";SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B:B)+0)})
```

Change `0` to `1` or `2`, if you want some blank row offset.

Comment: Receiving this error `Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected`

Comment: @ShRa Check edited answer

Comment: Sorry for being late @TheMaster the problem with your answer is whenever i sort the data A to Z Array keeps the Sequence does not change according to the rows.