# How to Stop Overwriting Manual Pasted data in Google Sheet attached to Google Form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I created a Google Sheet that will record entries from Google Forms. There are many people that submit their respective facility's information before this google Forms.

I have pasted all data into that Google Sheets which records the entry from Google Form Whenever any new entry is submitted through google Forms it Overwrite the data that i have pasted manually.

I hope there will be solution to it. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you paste this data _before_ the ones from Google Forms? Does it overwrite its own data? Or it just follows from where it is?

Comment: Yes I have pasted data from row 2 to row 100 manually when i submit a new response from google Form it overwrites the data in row 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the Form Responses Sheet? The issue is that forms doesn't detect whether that row is populated or not. It depends on the count of responses rather than the content of the sheets.

I recommend that you create a sheet similar to the Form Responses where you do your manual inputs there, while the Form Responses sheet will handle form submissions.

Then you collate both sheets' data into another sheet which combines both form data and manual inputs.

#### Form response sheet:

[image: form]

#### Manual input sheet:

[image: manual]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Step by step:

1. Add the header first

```
'Form Responses 1'!A1:C1;
```

2. Add both data from form and manual sheet, then sort them using the timestamp (1st column)

```
sort({
filter('Form Responses 1'!A2:C, 'Form Responses 1'!A2:A <> ""); 
filter('Manual Inputs'!A2:C, 'Manual Inputs'!A2:A <> "")
}, 1, true)
```

3. Wrap them all in a curly bracket and output as 1 formula.

#### Final formula:

```
={'Form Responses 1'!A1:C1;
sort({
filter('Form Responses 1'!A2:C, 'Form Responses 1'!A2:A <> ""); 
filter('Manual Inputs'!A2:C, 'Manual Inputs'!A2:A <> "")
}, 1, true)
}
```

#### Submitted another form response:

[image: submit]

Comment: Thank you very much @NaziA this is marvelous

Comment: You're welcome @ShRa, glad I was of help.

Comment: Can you please help me with one more thing that is if i want to assign Unique Identifier in the Collated Data tab https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70010747/create-unique-id-from-0-to-upward-google-sheets/70012516#70012516 @NaziA